# Why is the button's event handler not firing?

Tags: c#, event-handling, windows-ce

I have a button with an event handler attached to it; 2-clicking it in the designer takes me to the code. Nowhere is the handler being unhooked/detached.

Some code I expected to run apparently isn't, so I put a bunch of MessageBox.Show()s in the handler, even at the very beginning, but none of them display (Note: I can't step through the code; I have to do it this way (arggghhhh)).

Here's some of the code:

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) // Find and list Records
{
    MessageBox.Show("Made it into btnFind_Click 0"); //TODO: Remove after debugging
    try
    {
        if (barcodeScanner != null)
        {
            // Turn off the listening
            barcodeScanner.BarcodeScan -= new BarcodeScanner.BarcodeScanEventHandler(barcodeScanner_BarcodeScan);
        }
            MessageBox.Show("Made it into btnFind_Click 1"); //TODO: Remove after debugging . . .
```

What could be preventing this code from being executed?

### UPDATE

Based on Mike C's idea, I added a MessageBox to the button_close handler. And when I click it, it does fire, but *only after other code runs first*; in this case, that other code doesn't prevent the Close_Click from (eventually) firing; with the Find button, though, it completely preempts it...IOW, I see the message from the Close button at the end when I click it, but I never see any of the messages in the Find button handler when I click it...

### UPDATE 2

Oh my lanta/say it ain't so, Joe! What's happening is an event is being kicked off in the form's overloaded constructor, and somehow this event is always fired just then (after clicking the find button). The message I'm seeing, that preempts everything in the button event handler, takes place in a method  which is called by processBarcode() which is called by processBarcode1(), which is invoked from barcodeScanner_BarcodeScan1(), which is called by barcodeScanner_BarcodeScan(), which is set up in frmEntry's overloaded constructor. If the previous coder had *intended* to drive me insane, he couldn't have done much better.

I guess there's a reason there's so much maintenance work "out there" or "out here": because there's so much bad broken code AND because the cats who make such a mess scratch a bunch of sand on it and walk away.

And this code is chock full of "huh?!?@#$%^?!?" moments, where bizarre gyrations are not commented on at all, and yet there is *this* comment:

```
// Check connection
checkConnection();
```

Comment: can you show the code where you attach the handler?

Comment: Just in case, make sure the method name is exactly the same as described in the .xaml file.

Comment: use find references on the method and verify that it actually is subscribed as eventhandler

Comment: it's windows ce, there are no .xaml files :-) @Clay Shannon - try to add manually this handler to event in your form constructor and check if it works.

Comment: This might sound random, but try what you've done here with a label. Attach a click handler to a label, and see if that works or not.

Comment: Do you find something like this: `this.btnFind.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnFind_Click);` (posted before seeing Sam's answer)

Comment: Yes, this is there:
this.btnFind.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnFind_Click);

Comment: @jt234: There is no xaml file; this is a prehistoric Windows CE app.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be that the `Click` event of the button is not subscribed to properly. If there is no line resembling

```
this.btnFind.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnFind_Click);
```

in the Designer file of the form, that's it.